# libgdx sensor collision detected but conditional code isn't firing

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I have a weird logic error that I am trying to sort through, however I am hitting a wall and can't seem to find my way around it. Perhaps the collective minds here can help!

So, what exactly is happening: I have a disc created in Box2D, as well as a sensor box created in box2D. The logic is simple, if the disc collides with the sensor. you win! The problem is, I can detect the collision between the ball and the sensor, however the condition, you win code isn't firing. Here's the code I am working with.

```
//instantiating the disc, ground, start platform, and win sensor
    disc = createCircleBody("Circle", 20, camera.viewportWidth / 2, 450, 0);
    disc.setUserData("disc");

    floor = createGround(tmpFloor);
    floor.setUserData("floor");

    platform = createPlatform(initPlatform);
    platform.setUserData("platform");

    winSensor = createWinSensor(tmpWinSensor);
    winSensor.setUserData("winSensor");

    //...   Code omitted for clarity   ... 

    world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

            Body fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
            Body fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

            // if the disc and the floor collide.
            if((fixtureA.getUserData() == disc.getUserData() && fixtureB.getUserData() == floor.getUserData()) || (fixtureA.getUserData() == floor.getUserData() && fixtureB.getUserData() == disc.getUserData())) {
                newDisc.add(tmpDisc);
                newDisc.add(tmpPlatform);
                bodiesForDeletion.add(disc);    // destroy the current disk
            }

            // if contact is detected between disc and WinSensor
            if (fixtureA.getUserData() == winSensor.getUserData() && fixtureB == disc.getUserData()) {

                Gdx.app.log("WIN_CONDITION", "You won!"); // This line won't fire. 

                //TODO: Create alert Box to notify user that they have won the game!
            }

            Gdx.app.log("beginContact", "between " + contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData() + " and " + contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData() + ".");
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {

            Body fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
            Body fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

            Gdx.app.log("endContact", "between " + contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData() + " and " + contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData() + ".");
        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact arg0, ContactImpulse arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact arg0, Manifold arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

The first collision detection works as intended. The disc collides with the ground box, is deleted and the start platform and a new disc are created outside the world step. I cannot figure out why this code isn't firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like in your if statement

> `if (fixtureA.getUserData() == winSensor.getUserData() && fixtureB == disc.getUserData()) {`

you are missing `.getUserData()` on your `fixtureB`.

Comment: I cannot tell you how long I have stared at that line of code. It was so simple I looked right over it! thank you for catching my mistake. I guess I just needed a second set of eyes on it haha.